# Using Metamethods in Lua: Error when using _add

Tags: lua

I'm working on a way to manage 2D Vectors and so far it's going fairly well. I have a module file that I'm calling Positions.lua that contains information for Vector2.new(X,Y)

I've never really used Metamethods before, so it's been a learning experience. I'm wanting to add two Vector2's together easily. This is my Metamethod function:

```
local vectorMethods = {
    _add = function(lhs,rhs)
        return Positions.Vector2.new(lhs.x+rhs.x,lhs.y+rhs.y);
    end
};
```

I've created this reading the Lua-users wiki page about metamethods.  Based on what I've seen, this should work if I link my Vector2 table to the metamethod using setmetamethod.

```
Positions = require("Positions");
X = Positions.Vector2.new(154.1,353.3);
Y = Positions.Vector2.new(5,5);
s,m = pcall(function() J = X+Y end);
if not s then
    print("Failed due to error: "..m);
end
```

This is the output I'm receiving:

> Failed due to error: main.lua:12: attempt to perform arithmetic on
>   global 'X' (a table value)

Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? I'm sorry for not showing the entire code, I felt like it's too much to post.

Sorry this post is poorly organized. I don't post on forums a lot.

Thank you for any help you can give me!

Comment: I've found that using
    J = (getmetatable(X)._add(X, Y))
works, which means that the metamethod itself is working.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the problem came from the fact that I was using a single  _ in _add instead of using __add.

I'm silly sometimes.
Thanks for reading, at least!